# Shared Disk names not updating

Tags: network, sharing

I have a headless MacMini attached to my Time Capsule that has a series of firewire disks attached (I use it to store photographs, and it runs CCC to backup one disk to another with lots of redundancy). As disks have failed over the years, some of them have had to be renamed, and they show up with their new names on the MacMini if I screenshare to it. But my MacBook Air still shows them when I connect to the MacMini for filesharing with their old names. Restarting, cleaning system cache, trashing logs, and trashing Finder plist have not corrected this. If I bring in a new computer that has never before connected to the MacMini it will show the old names too, so I assume this means the problem is on the MacMini, not on the machine accessing it. Recently, I added an iMac to the network to keep connected to my film scanners. I'm having the same problem with it's hard drive name. I changed it from its original name to iMac HD, but the original name still shows up for sharing the disk on other machines. It's confusing to have a network where all drives are called Macintosh HD, so I want the name change to show up across the network.
Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a fix, but I'm not sure what it did to correct the naming issue. While I was researching it I came across the method of connecting to a server by making a bookmark in a browser address bar. In the address bar I typed:
afp://user:password@IPaddressonLAN/iMac%20HD
with the proper username and password for my account on the iMac, the IP address for theIMac, and a %20 in place of the space in the disk's name, iMac HD. Then I selected it and dragged it to the desktop and double-clicking it mounts the desired disk with its new name. And best of all, now if I click on the iMac in the sidebar of a Finder window, it shows the disk as being called iMac HD instead of the old name.
I don't know what this has updated or where, but I'm not complaining if it works! It must have changed something on the iMac, not on my MBA. I say this because I checked with the computer that has never been connected to the iMac - when I posted my question I noted it also showed the old disk name (having never been connected to it at all under that name), and now it shows the new name for the disk. Something has been updated on the iMac itself has to be the explanation.